# Locking an API to App-Use only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, security, backend

I've written a rails back-end for the mobile app I'm working on and it occured to me that even though I'm using token authentication, anyone could write a malicious script that continually registers users / continually makes requests in attempts to fill the database / attack the server.

I guess there are two questions here:

1) What modifications would I need to make in order to ONLY allow API access from my mobile app

2) How can I protect my API urls?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things you can do to protect your API :

The simplest thing you can start with is verifying the user-agent header in your request. That usually gives you a good indicator of what the initiating device is.

That being said, it isn't always accurate and its definitely fakeable.

If you control the client side of the mobile app as well, you could encrypt the requests/responses with a cypher or key system which requires a key that only your mobile-app knows. Look at openssl for that... using a public/private key pair.

Token authentication is a good idea. I would actually look at oAuth or similar systems for authentication and keep your session timers short.

On top of that, you can probably add some rate control in order to limit consecutive calls from the same IP in a given timespan.

Finally, I would look at something like "fail2ban" or similar to automatically ban brute-force type attacks.

Comment: Thanks for the info about user-agent header. I've worked with encryption before, but the encryption key would have to be stored in the app. Android apps can be obfuscated, but they can also decompiled easily and, so how could I possibly hide this key?? Is there a way to obfuscate strings? And to hide the authentication token I guess I should use encryption as well...or just https?

Comment: https would definetely help. You're never safe from a man-in-the-middle attack but if your application validates the server side certificate, that makes it unlikely.
You are correct that an app can always be decompiled or reversed. You could look into use some sort of unique ID that only the mobile platform knows about (maybe something around the game center services ? or simply the IMEI of the mobile's modem ? iOS devices have a UUID as well)